# Swagger UI not loading Throwing 500 error

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am using spring doc openui for swagger doc. Below is the dependency I am using

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.9</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried `1.6.13 version` too.

No other extra config I used even url for swagger ui also default one.

when I tried to open this URL : `localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html` or `localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`

It is returning `500 error`

```
"{"error":{"description":"Duplicate key class Parameter{\n name: x-nodeId \n in header \n description:null \n required:true \n .... }, "code": 500, "instructions":"Contact Field Support"}}"
```

You can see same in Screenshot.

[image: swagger-500-err]

**Updated** **:**
The error is throwing for Header Parameters it seems. I have X-nodeId as header param for most of api's once I removed those. The error pointing to new header param, i.e

```
"{"error":{"description":"Duplicate key class Parameter{\n name: x-countryCode \n in header \n description:null \n required:true \n .... }, "code": 500, "instructions":"Contact Field Support"}}"
```